# How to indicate an error because all numbers are valid return values?

Tags: c

- Compiler: GCC 4.4.5 (Code::Blocks)
- Platform: Linux Kernel Version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian)

I am currently writing a function that converts character strings into double longs. I am aware that there is already a function that does this. I am simply writing this function for practice but I currently don't know what to do.

My function worked correctly when it could only handle positive double longs because I could return -1 if their was an invalid character in the string. But I want the function to be able to handle negative double longs as well as positive. I don't know what I am supposed to do in this situation because now all real numbers are valid return values. I thought about continuing the conversion even if invalid characters are present by either converting the invalid characters into their decimal values or simply ignoring the invalid characters and picking out only valid characters 0-9 (decimal 48-57). I also thought about returning a pointer to a double long and using a NULL address to indicate that an invalid character was found or maybe I could just set `errno` like the function `readdir()`. I am not sure how I would go about setting `errno` or if that is even allowed. So my question overall is what would you guys recommend I do in this situation? Also please note that I haven't included handling for negative double longs yet and the function will simply ignore invalid characters: for example `$&3%7AJ89` will be converted to 3789.

```
double long cstrtodl(const char *cstr)
{
double long power;
double long dl = 0;
int decimal_place;
int bool_decimal = 0;

for(decimal_place = 1; cstr[decimal_place] != '\0'; decimal_place++)
{
    if(cstr[decimal_place] == '.')
    {
        bool_decimal = decimal_place;
        break;
    }
}

for(decimal_place--, power = 1; decimal_place >= 0; decimal_place--, power *= 10)
{
    printf("[%i] = %i(%c)\nPOWER = %LF\nINTEGER = %LF\n", decimal_place, (int)cstr[decimal_place], cstr[decimal_place], power, dl);
    switch(cstr[decimal_place])
    {
        case 48:
            dl += 0 * power;
        break;

        case 49:
            dl += 1 * power;
        break;

        case 50:
            dl += 2 * power;
        break;

        case 51:
            dl += 3 * power;
        break;

        case 52:
            dl += 4 * power;
        break;

        case 53:
            dl += 5 * power;
        break;

        case 54:
            dl += 6 * power;
        break;

        case 55:
            dl += 7 * power;
        break;

        case 56:
            dl += 8 * power;
        break;

        case 57:
            dl += 9 * power;
        break;

        default:
            power /= 10;
        break;
    }
}

if(bool_decimal > 0)
{
    for(decimal_place = bool_decimal+1, power = 10; cstr[decimal_place] != '\0'; decimal_place++, power *= 10)
    {
        printf("[%i] = %i(%c)\nPOWER = %LF\nINTEGER = %LF\n", decimal_place, (int)cstr[decimal_place], cstr[decimal_place], power, dl);
        switch(cstr[decimal_place])
        {
            case 48:
                dl += 0 / power;
            break;

            case 49:
                dl += 1 / power;
            break;

            case 50:
                dl += 2 / power;
            break;

            case 51:
                dl += 3 / power;
            break;

            case 52:
                dl += 4 / power;
            break;

            case 53:
                dl += 5 / power;
            break;

            case 54:
                dl += 6 / power;
            break;

            case 55:
                dl += 7 / power;
            break;

            case 56:
                dl += 8 / power;
            break;

            case 57:
                dl += 9 / power;
            break;

            default:
                power /= 10;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return dl;
}
```

Comment: How about returning a NaN in case of unparsable input?

Comment: @wildplasser I didn't think C had NaNs.

Comment: Usually the implemented floating point types have, but I vote for setting `errno`.

Comment: IEEE 754 has NaNs. IIRC C supports/embodies/implements IEEE floats.

Comment: @everyone \*facepalm\* That's my second major SO brainfart today...

Comment: @wildplasser what exactly is NaNs I am assuming it is the max value of a double long? Would NaNs still work if the double long is an 80-bit extended percision type rather than an IEEE 754?

Comment: Please note that the usual term is `long double`, though the compilers are happy with `double long` as well.  Similar comments would apply to `int long unsigned long`; that would normally be written as `unsigned long long int` or just `unsigned long long`.

Comment: The standard floating point types do have NaNs. And the Nans are not part of the normal code-space (NaN != DOUBLE_MAX as you suggested). For the extended types (such as the 80 bit copro format): I guess it will be hardware/implementaion defined. But even the 80 bits format would need some trap values, and the ability to convert them to/from the native types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning a pointer is complicated and inefficient, because you'd have to `malloc` a buffer and then remember to `free` it. That's a lot of overhead for returning a simple, fixed-size value. Instead, you can return a status code and write the result to a pointer:

```
// returns zero on success, -1 on error
int cstrtodl(const char *cstr, long double *result);
```

For some purposes, it might also be useful to know how much of the string was consumed, if you don't necessarily read all of it. In that case, you can return a `size_t` or `ssize_t`, and either 0 (no input consumed) or -1 on error. The caller can then check whether anything unexpected follows the number in the input string.

Setting `errno` is perfectly allowed in C.

Comment: So you are saying I should return the number of characters read from the string and use a double long pointer to pass on the double long?

Comment: @JohnVulconshinz: that's what I would do and what many libraries do. If you don't care about the number of characters read, then a simple `int`-typed error code suffices.

Comment: This answer presents the most idiomatic C design. +1

Comment: This is actually better than passing error conditions in an extra argument, since ignoring errors means you just don't assign the return value; otherwise, you'd still need to pass `NULL`. So, +1.

Comment: If you want to return the number of characters read, you should use `size_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You have several options:

1. Using NAN as an error value. Keep in mind that you cannot check for NAN with `==`. You must use `isnan(x)` or `x!=x` to check whether `x` is a NAN.
2. Adding an additional `int *errorp` argument to store a flag (and possibly an error code) for whether an error occurred. This option has two sub-options: you may want to write a 0 on success, or you may want to leave the previous contents alone on success so that the caller can make multiple calls and only check at the very end whether any of them failed.
3. Switching things around: Passing a pointer to where to store the result, and using the return value for an error code. This approach encourages checking for errors after every call, but makes it difficult to use the result directly in expressions, which can be annoying.
4. Reporting the error through special thread-local state: either `errno`, the floating point exception flags (warning: some machines don't support fenv/exceptions!), or your own thread-local object. Depending on your perspective this may be wrong/ugly since it's a hidden information channel, but it can also be the most convenient for the caller.
5. Reporting the error through global state. Please, never do this. It precludes multi-threaded and clean library use of your code.

Answer (score 2):

`errno` can be used for this.  You need to `#include <errno.h>` in order to use it. You set `errno` to some predefined value, and the caller then checks it:

```
errno = 0;
cstrtodl(some_string);
if (errno != 0) {
    // Error occured.
}
```

Note that `errno` is thread-safe. If you write to it in one thread, the value isn't changed in other threads. So it's not just some global variable. It can even be not a variable at all, but internal compiler magic. But the point is, you can just treat it as if it were a thread-local variable.

Another way is to pass the error in an extra argument:

```
double long cstrtodl(const char *cstr, int *error)
{
    // ...
    if (error != NULL) {
        if (some_error_occured) {
            *error = SOME_CONSTANT_OR_MACRO;
        } else {
            *error = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The caller can then do:

```
int error;
cstrtodl(some_string, &error);
if (*error) {
    // Error occured.
}
```

Or, if the caller isn't interested:

```
cstrtodl(some_string, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either returning a pointer to the resulting double or NULL on error (as you suggested) or, as strtoul(), adding a pointer parameter which you point at the first unconverted character.

As for errno, it's just another global variable (just happens to be declared within libc) and it is just fine to assign your own value to it.

Comment: How would you return a pointer to the result? You would have to allocate storage for it, introducing a new nonsensical failure cause, or require the caller to pass you a pointer for where to store the result.